# Setting utf8mb4_unicode_ci as the default for all utf8mb4 character set tables

Tags: mysql, collation

I am running MySQL 5.7.19 in RDS and recently went through a conversion of everything to Character Set = UTF8MB4 and Collation = UTF8MB4_unicode_ci. I set the following parameter group settings and rebooted:

```
character_set_client = utf8mb4
character_set_connection = utf8mb4
character_set_database = utf8mb4
character_set_results = utf8mb4
character_set_server = utf8mb4
collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server = utf8mb4_unicodel_ci
```

My goals were:  for one to provide consistency on all databases, tables and columns. Second to stop requiring developers to specify character_set and collation when creating tables.

The problem I am running into is that when I look into the information_schema.collations table, utf8mb4_general_ci is still set to IS_DEFAULT yes. So when one of our servers connects and creates a temp table it's set up as utf8mb4_general_ci rather than utf8mb4_unicode_ci, unless they specify it in table creation, which I wan to avoid. In addition when I run show variables like 'coll%' I get the following:

```
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server    utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Which is the same problem, just on my laptop vs the server. Has anyone run into this and solved it?

Comment: Please file a bug (feature request) with bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?